# What is a dybbuk?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, soul, afterlife

I heard that a dybbuk is kind of like a soul that came back from heaven and inhabits a body.
1. Does anyone have any more information that would make the concept easier to picture?
2. Is there a specific reason for becoming a dybbuk?
3.Is there a way not to become a dybbuk or to get out of it once someone is one?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dybbuk

Comment: I dont know how well we can trust wikipedia for a jewish term

Comment: @DaniLevin Who do you think wrote the Wiki page? Plus you can check the source material at the bottom.

Comment: my favorite book on the subject https://www.amazon.com/Dybbuk-Gershon-Winkler/dp/091081838X

Comment: This question appears to relate to a topic in Jewish theater and folklore not related to Judaism. May be off-topic.

Comment: @ezra wiki pages can be edited easily (never an allowed site for school researches)

Comment: @DaniLevin That is why it was used as a comment and not as an answer. However it is a good place to start.

Comment: @Tesvov I don't know why this would be a topic in Jewish theater; there are numerous verified accounts of dybbuks (though admittedly there are many fantastical stories as well.) I remember a few years back looking into the story of the chofetz chaim and the dybbuk. Rav Elchonon Wasserman was chosen to exorcise it in the presence of a minyan of the CC's major talmidim. There were multiple first person reports written (including by Rav E. Wasserman himself) and they all were consistent with each other. I'm going to try and track down these sources to share here,

Comment: @Binyomin it's hardly verified http://daattorah.blogspot.com/2016/03/rav-nosson-kaminetsky-those-who.html

Comment: @DoubleAA even given that accounting, which raises questions about whether that specific girl had a real dybbuk or was just mentally ill, it seems clear that all the parties involved fully believed in the possibility of a dybbuk. The Chofetz chaim would not have gathered all those gedolei yisrael (rav elchonon wasserman, Rav. Y.S. Kahaneman and more) to attempt to remove a dybbuk if they believed that dybbuks were purely "a topic in Jewish theater and folklore."

Comment: @Binyomin the claim that "there are numerous verified accounts of historical people believing in dybbuks" didn't really need proving

Comment: @DoubleAA My point was when certain things are accepted by leading gedolei yisrael (not just "historical people") it's not "jewish theater and folklore." Compare: the belief in the ability to create a golem through kabbalah etc. is not just "jewish theater" as it's well supported by both Talmudic references and widespread (thought maybe not universal) rabbinic acceptance. The specific story of the Maharal's golem, however, is without support and is just folklore. That's the distinction- a widespread concept accepted by gedolei yisrael is not just "Jewish theater" even if any example might be.

Comment: @Binyomin for many many centuries leading gedolei yisrael thought the moon was a perfect sphere, thought the sun was 40 times the size of the earth, thought neptune didn't exist, thought the kidneys controlled memory, thought maggots don't have parents, ......

Comment: @Binyomin - could you provide any sources for your assertions?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think we're disagreeing. I'm not talking about "if gedolim believe it, it must be scientifically true" or even "gedolim can't be wrong." I'm specifically focusing on the idea of "Jewish theater" and I don't think any of your examples should be called that. Theater implies making up a plot or story; I'm discussing people seriously believing things to be factual (either on spiritual levels, or perhaps mistakenly on a physical level.) Maharal's golem could be considered theater, as can some dybbuk stories; but the concept of golems, or dybbuk, is not just "Jewish theater."

Comment: https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?v=52148 the first in a 3-part series on dybbukim. I thought it was good with a lot of info and sources. Note: slightly not for the faint of heart (I don't quite remember how graphic it gets, but I remember that the descriptions were quite creepy).

Answer (score 1):

I begin by noting that I am not a Kabbalist (Jewish mystic) and therefore I am no expert on the subject matter but this is what I found on the subject that may help to provide a greater understanding on the topic.

The term 'dybbuk' stems from the Hebrew root 'דבק', which means to 'cleave' or 'cling', which describes how the itinerant, sometimes evil, soul cleaves to the individual it possesses. (as expressed eloquently [here](https://www.thejc.com/judaism/rabbi-i-have-a-problem/what-can-i-do-if-i-am-haunted-by-a-dybbuk-1.49397))

Indeed, this concept of possession is brought down in Nach. In [Shmuel aleph 16:14](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.16.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) we are told about the following episode with King Shaul:

> וְר֧וּחַ ה' סָ֖רָה מֵעִ֣ם שָׁא֑וּל וּבִֽעֲתַ֥תּוּ רֽוּחַ־רָעָ֖ה מֵאֵ֥ת ה'׃
>
> *"Now the spirit of the LORD had departed from Saul, and an evil spirit from the LORD began to terrify him."*

The Late 16th Century saw the rise to prominence of the study of Kabbalah - Jewish Mysticism. Many scholars such as the Rabbi Yitzchak Luria (the Arizal), his student Rav Chaim Vital and Rav Moshe Cordovero all explored this notion of evil possession.

Perhaps the most famous of studies is the Shaar HaGilgulim (lit. the Gate of Reincarnation) which is based primarily on the Zohar in Parshas Mishpotim where gilgulim are discussed, it is from the writings of the Arizal and the book was recorded by his foremost disciple, Rabbi Chaim Vital. It is here that the concept of possession is discussed as a 'Ruach haRa'ah' an evil spirit.

The end of Shaar HaGilgulim relates a happening with Rav Chaim Vital who was called to oversee an exorcism of an evil possession that had taken hold in a girl called Esther. With the help of 10 gifted talmidei chachomim (Jewish sages) he commanded the spirt to depart. This caused Esther’s left foot to bounce upward which was interpreted as the spirit leaving her small toe.

In a similar vein, Rav Moshe Cordovero employed the term 'Ibbur Ra'ah' - An Evil Impregnation drawing on the fact that this possession attaches itself to soul.

Rabbi Yaakov Chaim Sofer (1870-1939, Baghdad and Israel), building on this explains in [Kaf HaChaim, Orach Chaim 46:32](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.46.32.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that is possible during one's lifetime, one might become 'pregnant' with one of these… Each night, one's soul gives an accounting before its Creator, and is judged for its deeds. Sometimes they will give it another soul, in the 'secret of pregnancy'.

It is worth noting though, whilst there is sufficient sources to say that such things exist/existed Rav Zeff Leff makes the following assertion [here](https://www.jewishpress.com/judaism/halacha-hashkafa/is-it-proper-should-a-jew-be-concerned-about-paranormal-phenomena-such-as-dybbuks-and-gilgulim/2019/08/28/):

> If concern means believing that these phenomena exist, then, yes, being concerned sensitizes one to the fact that aside from the physical world that we are aware of through our five senses, there is a spiritual world – just as real, if not more real, and more significant.
>
> If concern, though, means to fear these things or to let them interfere with one’s life, then we must know that they are in the realm of “hanistaros laShem Elokeinu” – “hidden things are in G-d’s realm.” And we therefore should not let them interfere with our behavior.

(A good book which speaks more at detail on these topics is [*Jewish Views of the Afterlife* authored by Simcha Paull Raphael](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ESOJDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA242&lpg=PA242&dq=chaim%20vital%20-%20shaar%20hagilgulim%20dybbuk&source=bl&ots=1KY0upvSyp&sig=ACfU3U3nr1GPeRahAthuRlM03et8kvoR6g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNlPzFr-_pAhXDilwKHYwiAKQQ6AEwAXoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=chaim%20vital&f=false) - starting on p. 239)

Comment: Did you quite large sections of this from https://www.thejc.com/judaism/rabbi-i-have-a-problem/what-can-i-do-if-i-am-haunted-by-a-dybbuk-1.49397

Comment: I saw the first paragraph about the meaning of the word and the source from Shmuel alef but the rest was my own research.

Comment: Plagiarism (aka stealing someone's wording) is not tolerated here. If you are quoting someone, reference it and format it with quotation marks.

Comment: I agree. I will edit accordingly now - but as I said I liked how he expressed the meaning which I have now sourced. Everything else was mine.

Comment: Liking how someone says something is indeed a good reason to quote them. See https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/76/759

Answer (score -8):

Dybbuk is a superstitious belief. It is often affiliated with mysticism. The roots can be traced to Roman Catholic accounts of exorcisms.

Answering briefly now.

1. It is the soul of a person who committed many misdeeds. This person usually tries to evade justice by invading a host, usually a woman. The only way to remove the dybbuk “possession” is to bring a mystic rabbi who will say some mystical prayers, magic, and enchantments. The dybbuk usually leaves the person by the foot.
2. My understanding is that it only happens to bad people.
3. My understanding is that one must be a good person to avoid becoming a dybbuk. If one is already a dybbuk they may pray to G-d to relieve him of his trouble. Or, the person may be entrapped on an apple, for example, and only receive redemption if and when a holy sage eats the apple. This can sometimes last for hundreds of years.

Comment: What does "bad" include, doing any sort of aveirah?

Comment: Are there any Jewish sources for this (mishna, gemara, medrish, rishonim, acharonim) other than theater and folklore?

Comment: @Tesvov No because I find that there are often little sources for late-mystical views.